# How to make use of the Dart Documentation on the Official Dart Website

Tags: dart, syntax, documentation, updates, dartdoc

I am new to the Dart Programming language and I am having problem locating where I can learn the current Syntax of the Dart language as regards things like CONSTRUCTORS, CLASSES, FUNCTIONS, VARIABLES and so on. My visit to the following is not yielding the result I need :
https://dart.dev/guides ; https://dart.dev/tutorials ; https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc and many others of the "dart.dev family" websites.

Please note, using https://dartpad.dev/? to run code syntaxes I see on other tutorial sites, indicates that such code styles (or Syntaxes) are outdated. So I need where, I can follow the latest updates.

My visit to hyperkill.org shows that they are not treating Dart programming for now, therefore any  suggestion of other site with updated code styles is welcome.  Thank you

Comment: You want https://api.dart.dev/.  Or, from the dart.dev website: Docs > API reference.

Comment: I have visited the http://api.dart.dev but couldn't find what I want. I hope to find a place in any of the dart-docs site or any other good site where I can learn the Syntax as a beginner and grow my knowledge therefrom.

Comment: @Philomental Something like the language tour? https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: @julemand101 Yeah. Thank you so much. From here, I've been able to navigate to what I really wanted.